# Configure an Envers RevisionListener via DI

Tags: c#, nhibernate, spring.net, nhibernate-envers

To add an audit trail to our application we decided to use NHibernate.Envers. To allow app specific tracking of revisions, the `DefaultRevisionEntity` was extended with user specific data.

```
public virtual void NewRevision( object revisionEntity )
{
  var revisionData = revisionEntity as Revision;
  if( revisionData != null )
  {
    // Set additional audit data.
    var identity = UserAccessor.CurrentIdentity;
    revisionData.UserId = identity.UserId;
    revisionData.EmployeeId = identity.EmployeeId;
    revisionData.UserName = identity.Name;
  }
}
```

Envers decides wich `RevisionListener` to use depending on the `RevisionEntity` attribute your class is decorated with:

```
[RevisionEntity( typeof( RevisionListener ) )]
```

I am using the ServiceLocator pattern to inject my accessor into the `RevisionListener`. Currently this is the only place where I have to use a ServiceLocator and really want to get rid of it.

Is there another, flexible way to inject my UserAccessor into the RevisionEntity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't today.

However - it sounds like a nice feature. Please add a JIRA ticket about it here
http://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NHE

Without giving it too much thoughts, I think it'll be pretty hard to enable users to do this with only attribute configuration though (if so, sort of an IoC needs to be built internally). Probably it can be accomplished by allowing to inject a revision listener singleton "somewhere close to IntegrateWithEnvers method".

Regards
Roger

Comment: Roger was kind enough to implement a solution: https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NHE-17 `var conf = new FluentConfiguration(); conf.SetRevisionEntity<MyRevisionEntity>(e => e.Number, e => e.TimeStamp, listener); nhConf.IntegrateWithEnvers(new AuditEventListener(), conf);`

Comment: i have same problem, but can't see how to add a reference to IUserAccessor that can be resolved by ninject. In exampled posted i see only some "new" passed as reference, but no interface references