# Nhibernate envers, use dependency injection to add user into revision entity

Tags: c#, nhibernate, ninject, nhibernate-envers

after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846996/configure-an-envers-revisionlistener-via-di) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7090636/ninject-nhibernate-and-auditing-in-asp-net-mvc) i come near solution but not to the end since i miss how to apply to my implementation.

i have this custon revision entity and revision listner:

```
public class _NHRevEntity : DefaultRevisionEntity {
    public virtual int IdUtente { get; set; }
}

public class EnversRevisionListener : IRevisionListener {
    private int _userName = 0;

    public EnversRevisionListener(IUserManagement um) : base() {
        _userName = um.UtenteCorrente.Id;
    }

    public void NewRevision(object revisionEntity) {
        var casted = revisionEntity as _NHRevEntity;
        if (casted != null) {
            casted.IdUtente = _userName;
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my SessionFactory

```
public class SessionFactory : IDisposable {
    private static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;
    private static NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration cfg = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration();
    static readonly object factorylock = new object();

    private static void InitializeSessionFactory() {
        _sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
                .ConnectionString(c => c.FromAppSetting("FluentNHibernateConnection"))
                .ShowSql())
                .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
                        )
                   .ExposeConfiguration(SetupEnvers)                       
                   .ExposeConfiguration(config => new SchemaUpdate(config).Execute(false, true))
                .BuildSessionFactory();
    }

    private static void SetupEnvers(NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration cfg) {
        var enversConf = new NHibernate.Envers.Configuration.Fluent.FluentConfiguration();
        enversConf.Audit<AutitedClass>();       
        IRevisionListener revListner = new EnversRevisionListener();
        enversConf.SetRevisionEntity<_NHRevEntity>(e => e.Id, e => e.RevisionDate, revListner);
        cfg.IntegrateWithEnvers(enversConf);
    }

    internal ISession OpenSession() {
        lock (factorylock) {
            if (_sessionFactory == null) {
                InitializeSessionFactory();
            }
        }
        NHibernate.ISession session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession();
        return session;
    }       
}
```

core problem is how to make work injection in `revisionListner`:

```
public EnversRevisionListener(IUserManagement um)
```

EDIT:

going on working i see the real quest: `private static void InitializeSessionFactory`: since it's static there is no way to inject reference in it. must find different way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved porting dependency injection into UnitOfWork Class:

public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
    {
        private static readonly object _syncRoot = new object();

```
    private ITransaction _transaction;
    private SessionFactory _nhHelper;
    internal ISession _session;
    public UnitOfWork(SessionFactory sf)
    {
        //Contract.Ensures(_session.IsOpen);
        _nhHelper = sf;
        InizializzaSessione();
    }
    public void InizializzaSessione()
    {
        lock (_syncRoot)
        {
            if (_session == null || _session.IsOpen == false)
            {
                _session = _nhHelper.OpenSession();
            }
        }
    }
```

and then session factory:

```
public class SessionFactory : IDisposable
{

    private static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;
    private static NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration cfg = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration();       

    static readonly object factorylock = new object();
    IUserManagement um; 

    public SessionFactory(IUserManagement ium)
    {
        um = ium;
    }

    private static void InitializeSessionFactory(IUserManagement um, bool genereteDB = false)
    {
        _sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
                .ConnectionString(c => c.FromAppSetting("FluentNHibernateConnection"))
                .ShowSql())
                .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
                                                .Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<SessionFactory>()
                        )
                   .ExposeConfiguration(config => SetupEnvers(config, um))                     
                   .ExposeConfiguration(config => new SchemaUpdate(config).Execute(false, true))
                .BuildSessionFactory();
    }

    private static void SetupEnvers(NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration cfg, IUserManagement um)
    {
        try
        {
            var enversConf = new NHibernate.Envers.Configuration.Fluent.FluentConfiguration();

            IRevisionListener revListner = new EnversRevisionListener(um);
            enversConf.SetRevisionEntity<RevisionEntity>(e => e.Id, e => e.RevisionDate, revListner);
         }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

    }

    internal ISession OpenSession()
    {
        lock (factorylock)
        {
            if (_sessionFactory == null)
            {
                InitializeSessionFactory(um);
            }
        }
        NHibernate.ISession session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession();

        return session;
    }
}
```